# Postgres - remove unique contraint (does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, unique, alter-table, not-exists

I have following table:

[image]

I have created unique constraint `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_item_media_idx ON mediagalleryitem (article_id, media_id);`

Now, I want to remove it and it is impossible for me. When I execute `ALTER TABLE "mediagalleryitem" DROP CONSTRAINT unique_item_media_idx;` it tells me: **constraint "unique_item_media_idx" of relation "mediagalleryitem" does not exist**

When I run from CLI `\d mediagalleryitem` I get:

```
Indexes:
"mediagalleryitem_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"unique_item_media_idx" UNIQUE, btree (article_id, media_id)
"idx_1c5848117294869c" btree (article_id)
"idx_1c584811ea9fdd75" btree (media_id)

Foreign-key constraints:
"fk_1c5848117294869c" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES article(id)
"fk_1c584811ea9fdd75" FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES media(id)
```

Whwere is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is an index, not a constraint. You can drop it using `DROP INDEX unique_item_media_idx`. Just as you created an index, you remove an index.

Comment: Aha, it is "constraint" using index. Thank you a lot.